# How to change the default ListTileTheme

Tags: flutter

I am unhappy with the default `ListTile` look and want to theme it. Specifically, I am unhappy with the subtitle text color -- it is a light gray and it simply lacks sufficient contrast with the background surface to be easily legible.

I already have code that creates a custom `ThemeData`, but I don't really see any documentation that explains how to customize it to impact ListTiles.

*Is this documented somewhere?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no ability to specify a global ListTileTheme. Instead, you can use ListTileTheme to provide theme for everything below it since it's a InheritedWidget. To do so, just wrap your child widget with ListTileTheme and that's all. Additionally, it has constructor `merge` which will try to find ListTileTheme above current one, and, if it finds any, will merge your styles with styles from the parent.

For example

```dart
ListTileTheme(
        //properties you want to add
        child: /// your child widget that has ListTile's anywhere in the tree
      ),
```

Or

```dart
ListTileTheme.merge(
        //properties you want to merge with any parent ListTileTheme, if there's any
        child: /// your child widget that has ListTile's anywhere in the tree
      ),
```

If something, you can follow [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31247) to track global ListTileTheme implementation progress

Comment: This works for me when I want to reduce the gap between the checkbox & its title.
`ListTileTheme(horizontalTitleGap: 0, child: CheckboxListTile(...),)`

Answer (score 0):

```
body: Center(
      child: ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
          title: const Text("Trix's airplane"),
          subtitle: const Text(
            'The airplane is only in Act II.',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
          ),
          enabled: true,
          onTap: () {/* react to the tile being tapped */}),
    ),
```

please refer above code for your refernce, if you are looking for subtitle color of listtile object. just need to style it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to customize the list tile in a flutter project.
Here is what I did:
I wrapped the listile in an `Ink` widget and specified the `color:` property to give it background-color.
`title:` and `subtitle:` take `Text()` widgets which can be styled and their color can be changed by using: `style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)`.
`leading:` and `trailing:` mostly contain icons which also have a `color:` property.